# Placing the value inside the text field loads the entire page, So Is there any function which will wait for the page load?

Tags: watir

Placing the value inside the text field loads the entire page, So Is there any function which will wait for the page load?

There are certain kind of a text_field which I am automating in which when I place the value like

```
b.text_field(:id,'something').set 'hi'
```

It refresh the entire page or it reloads the page, but the above code only wait until element present and place the value inside the text field but it doesn't take care of what happens after that.

Is there any function I can write like given below,

```
b.text_field(:id,'something').set 'hi'

b.waitForPageToLoad # Code like this?
```

Or it there any function to check whether the page got loaded completely?

I have put this question in watir-general as well, but I find no reply, so I am writing here.

Answer (score 1):

With dynamic website implementations, the phrase "the page has finished loading" doesn't really mean anything any more.
The best practice is to wait for the thing you are interacting with next. Watir 6 has made this much more automatic, but some additional logic may still be required to accomplish what you need.

Since the details that have been provided do not make sense any longer, here are a few generic principles that might help.

Watir & Selenium will both automatically wait for a page to finish reloading once it detects that it has started to reload.

Watir will automatically wait for an element to be in a state to interact with it if you take an action on that element.

`Element#set` is a combination of `Element.clear` and `Element.send_keys`

If the javascript on your page does things when an element is or is not the active element, it might be necessary to click on the element before or after sending text to it.

It is possible to send [symbols representing keys](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/keys.rb#L28-L106), like `browser.text_field(name: 'first').set "foo", :tab`

If you need to be able to know that a page has been refreshed in order to continue your test, you can create a variable that stores the element locators, then take an action on that element variable (which actually looks up the element), and then wait for that element to go stale like this:

```
element = browser.text_field(name: 'first')
element.set "foo"
# do something that causes the page to be refreshed
element.wait_until(&:stale?)
```

Hopefully some combination of these things related to your concerns will help you figure out a solution to your problem.

Comment: hi, I have written this code `b.text_field(:id,'policyStartDate').set '15/02/2017'

b.text_field(:id,'policyStartDate').wait_until(&:stale?)`  But it's throwing this error `C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/watir-6.0.3/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:486:in `stale?': Can not check staleness of unused element (Watir::Exception::Error)`

Comment: Since this is not how Watir is intended to be used, it is a bit hacky. You have to use a variable like I specified above. The element from the driver will get located/used with the `set` command and then can "go stale" when the page refreshes.

Comment: hi, Since my reply is long, I have updated my reply in water general, Can you please look into that?

Comment: I honestly couldn't follow a lot of what you said there, and I'm very glad I don't have to use the website you are trying to automate for. :) It was mentioned that can send tabs with your `#set` commands if that is what is triggering the refresh, and if that is what causes it, you probably don't need the waiting for stale. Beyond that, I can't do much more without access to the site.

Comment: You are saying Watir is powered by Selenium but my selenium framework does the Job perfectly!

Comment: Selenium is just the translation code for commands to be sent to and from a server or browser driver via a standardized protocol. Watir sends these same commands as whatever selenium framework you are using, but it also does some additional processing designed to make it easier to test web pages. It appears that some of the assumptions made by Watir conflicts with how you are trying to test your particular website. Your continued attempts to explain what is happening no longer makes any sense to me, so I'm not going to be able to investigate further without a reproducible test case.

Comment: send_keys works fine, but set is not working, In the `set` method you people have combined `clear and send_keys` methods so what happens is every time it clears the text_field as expected but when it executes the send_keys methods, it falls into the error but in your rescue block you have written `retry` keyword so it continues to retry indefinitely. The Error is `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError` Code follows  `begin
        send exist_check
        yield
      rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError
        retry
end`